# help me? please with program on c++

Tags: c++

I work in Microsoft visual c++ 6.0 and I don't understand why next mistakes appear

```
d:\program files\microsoft visual studio\vc98\include\iostream(16) : error C2653: 'ios_base' : is not a class or namespace name
d:\program files\microsoft visual studio\vc98\include\iostream(16) : error C2144: syntax error : missing ';' before type 'int'
d:\program files\microsoft visual studio\vc98\include\iostream(16) : error C2501: '_STD_BEGIN' : missing storage-class or type specifiers
d:\program files\microsoft visual studio\vc98\include\iostream(16) : fatal error C1004: unexpected end of file found
Error executing cl.exe.
```

Source:

```
#include stdio.h
#include conio.h
#include iostream.h
#include stdlib.h 
#include string

using std::string;
#define MAX_SIZE 32000

class Pets
{
public:
    Pets(const string &,const string &,const string &,const string &,int=0);

    void setAge (const string &); 
    string getAge() const;

    void setStatus (const string &); 
    string getStatus() const; 
    void setColour (const string &); 
    string getColour() const; 

    void setKind (const string &); 
    string getKind() const; 
    void setCost (int); 
    int getCost() const; 

    virtual void print() const; 
    virtual ~Pets()=0;

private:
    string age;
    string status;
    string colour;
    string kind;
    int cost;

};


Pets::Pets(const string &vozr,const string &state, const string &cvet,
           const string & vid, int price)
           :age(vozr),status(state),colour(cvet),kind(vid)
{
    setCost(price);
}


void Pets::setAge(const string &vozr)
{
    age=vozr;
}


string Pets::getAge() const
{
    return age;
}


void Pets::setStatus(const string &state)
{
    status=state;
}


string Pets::getStatus() const
{
    return status;
}


void Pets::setColour(const string &cvet)
{
    colour=cvet;
}

string Pets::getColour() const
{
    return colour;
}

void Pets::setKind(const string &vid)
{
    kind=vid;
}

string Pets::getKind() const
{
    return kind;
}

void Pets::setCost(int price)
{
    cost=(price>0 && price<MAX_SIZE)? price : 0;
}

int Pets::getCost() const
{
    return cost;
}

void Pets::print() const
{
    cout<<getAge()<<' '<<getStatus()<<' '<<getColour()<<' '<<getKind()<<' '<<getCost()<<endl;

}

class Cats:public Pets 
{


};

class Dogs:public Pets  //êëàññ ñîáàêè
{

};


void welcome() 
{
    cout<<"==============================================================================="<<endl;
    cout<<"||                                                                           ||"<<endl;
    cout<<"||                       *******Pet Kennel*******                            ||"<<endl;
    cout<<"||                                                                           ||"<<endl;
    cout<<"==============================================================================="<<endl;
    cout<<"press any key to continue...."<<endl;
}


// void menu() - ôóíêöèÿ âûâîäà ìåíþ íà ýêðàí
void menu() 
{   
    cout<<"||                              M E N U                                      ||"<<endl;
    cout<<"==============================================================================="<<endl;
    cout<<"|| 1 ||      Show Pet's list                                                 ||"<<endl;
    cout<<"|| 2 ||      Enter new pet                                                   ||"<<endl;
    cout<<"|| 3 ||      Edit pet                                                        ||"<<endl;
    cout<<"|| 4 ||      Sort pets                                                       ||"<<endl;
    cout<<"|| 5 ||      Delete info                                                     ||"<<endl;
    cout<<"|| 6 ||      Find status                                                     ||"<<endl;
    cout<<"|| 0 ||      Quit                                                            ||"<<endl;

    cout<<"==============================================================================="<<endl;


    cout<<"Enter number of the operation:"<<endl;
}

void main()     
{
    welcome();
    getch();
    system("cls");

    menu(); 

    getch();
}
```

Comment: Could somebody with sufficient privileges move this to SO and fix the formatting?

Comment: please dont use **BOLD** letters, and it is not the correct place to ask this question!

Comment: If you are wonder why you are being downvoted, here is the reason: 1.: this should be asked on stackoverflow, not here. 2.: You didn't put the minimal effort of correctly formatting and phrasing your question.

Comment: The bold probably came with the #'s in the include directives. This should be migrated to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Put angle brackets around stdio.h etc.

Answer (score 4):

You should be using

```
#include <iostream>
```

not

```
#include <iostream.h>
```

etc.

Comment: And other includes need <> too.

Comment: Also, add `using std::cout` near `using std::string`, and maybe replace `getch` by usage of `std::cin` (not sure about this one).

Comment: i am quite sure its his first C++ program. i am happy cos hes gonna be on a helluva ride

Comment: @RYUZAKI LOL. What were they thinking of when C/C++ was invented? (Easy to use was definitely not a consideration!)

Comment: @danny. no these are not easy to use today. but it was the 60's  when these languages were invented man. at that time of course they WERE the easiest to use langs. But i still love them both. i feel at home when coding in C/C++. Hats off to both langs. decades after their invention ; they are still relevent today. also most prescriptive languages borrow their syntax from C.

Comment: When was the **easier** Pascal invented?